# MSVC casts pointers from any type to any type implicitly in .c files, not giving errors or warnings. Why?

Tags: c, implicit-conversion, visual-studio-2022

See this example:

```
FILE* f = NULL; // MSVC warns if I do not initialize them.
char* s = NULL;
s = f; // these two lines compiles in .c file but not in .cpp file
f = s; // this is really dangerous!
```

I found this bug (or, maybe it is a feature in MSVC?),
because several hours ago, I wrote something like this:

```
fread(f, 1, size, str); // crash! exchange f and str!
```

which compiles without any warning, let alone errors, and crashes my program until I change the file extension to .cpp.

Why doesn't MSVC perform such a basic check in .c files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSVS **does** warn you (https://godbolt.org/z/e5oq7fexM):

```
<source>(16): warning C4133: '=': incompatible types - from 'FILE *' to 'char *'
<source>(17): warning C4133: '=': incompatible types - from 'char *' to 'FILE *'
```

> Why doesn't MSVC perform such a basic checks .c files?

It does, you probably have disabled all the warnings.

> these two lines compiles in .c file but not in .cpp file

Because `C++` & `C` are different languages. `C` allows implicit pointer conversions, `C++` does not. It is why you need to cast the result of `malloc` in **`C++`**, but you do not in **`C`**

You can use `-WX` option to treat warnings as errors and your program will not compile anymore https://godbolt.org/z/GvssPbxEv

```
<source>(10): error C2220: the following warning is treated as an error
<source>(10): warning C4133: '=': incompatible types - from 'FILE *' to 'char *'
<source>(11): warning C4133: '=': incompatible types - from 'char *' to 'FILE *'
```

You can learn more about MSVC options here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/compiler-option-warning-level?view=msvc-170

Comment: Oh, it is due to my build tool. It builds in release mode by default, supressing all warnings. In C such problems are reported as warnings, and in C++, they are reported as errors. So I didn't see those warnings in .c file. Thanks a lot!

Comment: "C allows implicit pointer conversions" C does _not_, except for void pointers and conversions from null pointer constants.

Comment: @LeYoung You need to fix your build tool ASAP. Suppressing warnings is a good way to get into trouble.